# Wordpress - Trigger script when search string entered into AJAX seach field?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, seo, event-tracking

I have a website built in Wordpress which is using the "BWL Knowledge Base Manager" plugin which provides an AJAX search bar.

Our SEO Manager has provided us with the following tracking script which needs to be triggered when someone enters a search string into the search bar:

```
﻿<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
window.dataLayer.push({
'event': 'search'
'Dlv-Search': 'ger', //recorded under “s”
});
</script>
```

(Where, obviously, 'ger' is to be replaced with whatever the user has entered into the search field).

It turns out that I have very little idea of how to implement this.  Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code looks more intimidating than it is. You should be able to add it straight to your search bar, perhaps on the `keydown` or `onchange` events. It may be cleaner if you wrap it in a function though.

```
<script>
    function SO_64130617_search( el, e ){
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        window.dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'search'
            'Dlv-Search': el.value,
        });
    }
</script>
```

Then just add that function to your input on whatever event you want to handle it on:

```
<input type="search" id="your-search" onchange="SO_64130617_search(this,event);" />
```

**Edit:**

Since you're unable to modify the HTML of the input, you should be able to bind an event handler to it instead. Check out this snippet:

```js
var search = document.querySelector('#s');
if( search != null ){
    search.addEventListener('change', function(e){
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        window.dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'search',
            'Dlv-Search': this.value,
        });

        console.log( window.dataLayer );
    });
}
```

```html
<input id="s" />
```

Run the snippet, and the `change` event will log the dataLayer variable as soon as you tab away or click. The `change` (`onchange`) events require you to *leave* the field. You may need to use `keydown` or `keyup` or something, but that can create a LOT of function calls, at which point you'd need to look at using a typing timeout or something.

Comment: The difficulty is though that the search bar is generated by a third-party plugin, so I can't edit the html of the input field (or if I do, I'll never be able to run any updates to the plugin when they're released on wordpress.org).
The input field has the id "s", so I have tried putting into my footer.php file:

    `jQuery("#s").on('change', function(){console.log("WORKING");});`

But the console is not showing anything when I enter text into the search bar.

Comment: I updated the code a bit with a working snippet. Make sure that you're actually leaving the field (click out of it, tab, etc.) if you're using the `change` event

Answer (score 0):

Ah hah!  So it appears that the plugin is somehow generating the search input field after the DOM is initially loaded.  So this appears to have done the trick:

I have created the function (Thanks Xhynk for the suggestion):

```
function SO_64130617_search( el, e ){
    console.log(el.value);
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    window.dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'search',
        'Dlv-Search': el.value,
    });
}
```

And then I have added the following to my child-theme's footer.php file:

```
jQuery("#s").ready(function(){
    console.log("I showed up");
    jQuery("#s").change(function(){
        SO_64130617_search(this,event);
    });
});
```

So now it is waiting and checking to see when "#s" is actually ready before trying to do anything with it.